# How to enable past dates in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I am seeing a lot of questions in stack overflow regarding disabling past dates in bootstrap datepicker.

But i want to enable past dates in bootstrap datepicker.

Here is my code, and i don't know what i miss in this.

```
<input type='text' id="campaignCreateDate" data-date-format="dd-M-yyyy" class="form-control datePicker" name="proposed_start_date"/>
```

and this is my js script

```
$('#campaignCreateDate').datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',            
    }).datepicker('setDate',new Date());
```

I also tried with only a simple tag as below:

```
<input type='text' id="testStartDate" class="form-control datePicker" name="proposed_start_date"/>
```

without any code in js, but still the past dates are not shown.

i.e, if today is 04/12/2018, i am not able to select 03/12/2018 or any dates before that.

Comment: which datepicker you are using , provide link

Comment: past dates are already enabled in your code, where is the problem?

Comment: Datepicker for Bootstrap v1.7.0 (https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

Comment: @Justcode no it's not enabled for me, I don't know why?

Comment: @KevinRED https://jsfiddle.net/6v5hogy7/ check this

Comment: it is working in jsfiddle, so why does its not working in my code?

Comment: is there any other details needed?

Comment: this was the actual code `$('#campaignCreateDate').datepicker({
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
        startDate: new Date()
    }).datepicker('setDate',new Date());` but i removed the `startDate: new Date()` part and gave a refresh, but still its not working for me

Comment: by default all date are enabled in datepicker.

Comment: So why this is happening here?

Comment: @KevinRED which version of Bootstrap are you using? Do you see any JS errors in console?

Comment: After removing `, startDate: new Date() ` make sure you clear cache and check..

Comment: @kiranvj, I don't see any errors in my console. The bootstrap version i am using is `Bootstrap v4.0.0-beta (https://getbootstrap.com)`.

Comment: I cleared my cache, but still the same results

Comment: I got it working friends. Thanks everyone

Comment: @KevinRED can we know what was the issue?

Comment: There was another main.js that was over writing the config where I was removing startDate and all...thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bojwcze9/1/) i created to help you out.

```
var today = new Date();

$("#campaignCreateDate").datepicker({
  autoclose: true,
  format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
  endDate : today,
  todayHighlight: true
});
```